# How to get the content of dynamic layouts in android

Tags: android, layout

```
**
```

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXtjS.png)

I have parsed an XML file and inflated in dynamic layouts. On clicking
on any layout a dialog fragment opens, but I'm unable to detect which layout
has been selected. I want to get the text view in that layout to pass
in dialog fragment invoked by clicking on the layout. I tried to `setId(count)`,
but when I get id on click listener it gives id of the last layout. Please edit my code or any link with details as I am a beginner. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I47CZ.png)

**

```
//code of fragment is below:

package com.appknoll.studentdatacollection.midwayapp;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    public static FragmentOne newInstance(){
        return new FragmentOne();
    }
    List<XMLParserObject> posts = null;
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    ViewGroup layout;
    GridView gridView;
    GridViewCustomAdapter gridViewCustomAdapter;
    List<Attributes.Name> name = new ArrayList<Attributes.Name>();
    public static final int PICKER = 1;
    Integer id;
    String lo;
String size;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        layout=(ViewGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+getTag(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                DFragment dialogFragment = new DFragment ();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("item_name",lo);
                dialogFragment.setArguments(args);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(dialogFragment, PICKER);
                dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample Fragment");
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
       try {
           posts = parser.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("rt_items.xml"));
           //posts = parser.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("rt_images"));
           int count = 0;
            for (XMLParserObject post : posts) {
                String name2=post.getName().toString();
                if(contains( name2, "Sushi" )) {
                    count++;
                    LinearLayout lii = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());
                    lii.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(600, 800));
                    //lii.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    lii.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                   lii.setId(count);
                    id= lii.getId();
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lii.setTag(post.getName());
                   //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+lii.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lii.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
                    lii.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    layout.addView(lii);
                    TextView name = new TextView(this.getContext());
                    name.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    name.setText(post.getName());
                    name.setTextSize(30);
                    name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#191970"));
                    lii.addView(name);
                    TextView Price = new TextView(this.getContext());
                    Price.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    Price.setText(Integer.toString(post.getUnit_price()) + "/-");
                    Price.setTextSize(40);
                    Price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                    lii.addView(Price);
                    TextView description = new TextView(this.getContext());
                    description.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    description.setText(post.getDescription());
                    description.setTextSize(15);
                    description.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    lii.addView(description);


                    ImageView image = new ImageView(this.getContext());
                    String image2 = post.getName().toString();
                    if (contains(image2, "1")){
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sushiroll1);
                    } else if(contains(image2, "2")){
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sushiroll2);
                    }else if(contains(image2, "3")){
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sushiroll3);
                    }
                    lii.addView(image);
                }
         }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return rootView;
    }


    public boolean contains( String haystack, String needle ) {
        haystack = haystack == null ? "" : haystack;
        needle = needle == null ? "" : needle;

        return haystack.toLowerCase().contains( needle.toLowerCase() );
    }



    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, do not post images from the outside sites as part of your questions.

Comment: @Gasper this is image from my own app. as i was using emulator in office I recorded a clip n right now I dun have office machine with me thats y i just took screenshot from that clip :)